# OxyPlot : ColumnSeries/BarSeries display value of each column

Tags: wpf, stackedbarseries, oxyplot

In my WPF app, I use OxyPlot. I bind my data to the PlotModel and all is working well.

I want to display the value of each column on the chart. Is it possible?

For reference, this [example of BarSeries](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BarSeries&referringTitle=Series) on site, I wish to show actual value of Apples of 2009, 2010 & 2011 respectively on each column. i.e. value of Value1 for the 2009Apples column, Value2 for 2010Apples and so on.

I looked up at the APIof the BarSeries (For WPF ColumnSeries used interchangeably). 
Tutorials of Bar & other plots. But couldn't find such thing anywhere.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just set the `LabelFormatString` property of your series.

```
var theSeries = new ColumnSeries();
theSeries.LabelFormatString = "{0:F2}"; // Example: 1.2311 will display like "1.23"

// Add your columns
theSeries.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(someValue);
// ...
```

There is also an optional property you can set called `LabelPlacement`. The default value is `LabelPlacement.Outside`:

```
theSeries.LabelPlacement = LabelPlacement.Middle;
```

Comment: Thanks for support. FYI, FormatString is not options, u got to enter else nothing shows up.